# How old were Sting and Rogue relative to the other Dragon Slayers at this key point in the timeline?

Tags: fairy-tail

So anyway, in the latest chapter, it was revealed that:

> Natsu and the 4 other Dragon Slayers from 400 years ago actually met some time before they were sent to the future. Quoting Zeref, most likely because of the dragons in their bodies making this stuff (I forgot the name) to prevent them from turning into dragons themselves, they have mostly forgotten about meeting.
>  
>  Before they time travelled, they all seemed the same age. And Lucy's mother opened the gateway (I assume) just once for them all. She didn't have all keys and became ill until she died, so I think we can definitely assume she didn't do it again.
>  
>  Then how is it that Sting & Rogue are generally the same age as Natsu in the past, yet have to catch up to Natsu, Gajeel and Wendy who are frozen (petrified, Fairy Sphere'd) for 7 years?

I mean, it could be a reason we don't know yet. Or am I just missing something VERY simple?

Comment: Did you know?  This site has [special markup](http://anime.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) for spoilers.

Comment: "as for Sting and Rogue, who were around the same age as Wendy, They Idolized the two of you as their adopted older brothers". They certainly look the same age, but it was clearly stated that Natsu and Gajeel were older than Sting and Rogue.

Comment: @Ryan that is correct as per the latest Manga chapter. Natsu, Gajeel were the same age. Sting, Rogue and Wendy were the same age. Sting and Rogue grew up to look like the same age as that of Natsu and Gajeel and older than Wendy when they were frozen in time for 7 years in Fairy Sphere.

Comment: Okay it may be very likely that they were never all the same age but all traveled at the same time Natsu and Gajeel are 7 years older than Sting,Rogue,and Wendy. The three 20 and the other two 27 but all traveled at the same time some part about it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Sting and Rogue are the same age as Wendy, in the manga the three are currently about "20" in the latest chapter (I am excluding the +400 years). If my memory serves right, Natsu & Gajeel are both "27".

Now the problem is working out the age different in the past, this isn't all to hard. Wendy was "12" when she was first introduced (x784). The Dragon Slayers arrived in (x777), so it's 12-7=5. Wendy was "5" years of age. Now Sting and Rogue are the same age as her, so those three were "5" years old. Now assuming I'm correct about Natsu's & Gajeel's age, they would've been 12 at the time.

Now I'm not sure if this answers the question, but I hope it does. Just keep in mind that Fairy Tail has a habit of making 12 year old kids look even younger than what they are. Easy way to tell is watch the Fairy Tail OVA 8.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Wendy, Sting and Rogue were five before they got sent four hundred years into the future, Natsu and Gajeel were, if you go by the guesstimated ages, were eleven back then in x777. In x784, it's estimated that Wendy, Sting and Rogue are 12 and Natsu and Gajeel are 18 along with Gray, while Lucy is 17 confirmed. In x791 Wendy would remain 12 while Natsu and Gajeel are still 18 and Sting and Rogue are 19. 
So there you have it, I don't know what their age would be in the manga currently, but these are my estimates till year x791.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Anime & Manga SE! It would be nice if you could provide references to the source material/author's notes/external references (wiki etc...) to support your answer.